# HTML5 Audio play two sounds in IOS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

i want to play 2 sounds in ios and since it could not be done, i defined 2 audio objects.

i start playing the first sound and when want to play the second, i pause the first and wait till the second end, then i resume playing the first from the point it reached.

you can check the following code, if i remove the alert("test"); the first audio start playing from zero and so current time don't work!

kindly help.
Thanks,

```
var PlayedTime = 0; ; //in seconds
var AudioObj;       
var audioType = '.mp3';
var isResume = false;
$(document).ready(function () {

    if (!!AudioSound.canPlayType('audio/ogg') === true) {
        audioType = '.ogg' //For firefox and others who do not support .mp3
    }

    AudioObj = document.getElementById('AudioSound');

    document.getElementById('AudioSound').addEventListener('ended', function () {                
        resume();
    });
});
function play1() {
    AudioObj.src = "Images/Sound1" + audioType;
    AudioObj.load();           
}
function play2() {
    PlayedTime = AudioObj.currentTime;  

    AudioObj.pause();
    AudioObj.src = "Images/Sound2" + audioType;
    AudioObj.load();         
    AudioObj.play();
}

function resume() {            
    isResume = true;
    AudioObj.pause();
    AudioObj.src = "Images/Sound1" + audioType;
    AudioObj.load();            
}

function JumpAudio() {
    AudioObj.currentTime = 36;
}
function DataLoadedtoPlay() {
    AudioObj.play();
    if (isResume) {
        isResume = false;
        try {
            alert("test");
            AudioObj.currentTime = PlayedTime;
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert("catch");
        }
    }
}


<div id="containerAud">
    <audio id="AudioSound" onloadeddata="DataLoadedtoPlay()"></audio>
</div>

<input type = "button" onclick="play1()" value="click1"/>
<input type = "button" onclick="play2()" value="click2" />
<input type = "button" onclick="JumpAudio()" value="JumpAudio" />    
</div>
```

Comment: I had a strange behaviour with wekit audio (chrome), it was: `currentTime` is _read-only_ until you set the `src` manually (it worked even with `AudioObj.src = AudioObj.src`. so, you might want to see if the `currentTime` you're setting is really changed. then, you could try to replace your alert - line, with that one and see if it works.

Comment: it didn't work in IOS, thanks anw